# How to edit a particular cell in listcontrol?

Tags: mfc

I am having a listcontrol where I am supposed to edit cell's of second column.
And this should be a list control but not a gridcontrol.
Is it possible to edit cell's of particular column in listcontrol ? If any way exist please let me know how to achieve it.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `CListCtrl::SetItemText`
[(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sya0wk5k.aspx)

Use the second parameter to specify the column.

Answer (score 0):

[CQuickList](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8112/CQuickList), a CListCtrl derived control, allows in-place edit of subitems.